# unclaimed Intel video card after upgrade to 20.04 and reinstalling ubuntu-desktop

Tags: drivers, 20.04, intel

I updated to Ubuntu 20.04 from 18.04 and had at first problems with booting (because my /boot is vfat and kernel could not be updated). Also the metapackage `ubuntu-desktop` was not installed so I finally managed to reinstall ubuntu desktop.

Now I have the problem that the intel card is unclaimed

```
     sudo LANG=C lshw -C video
      *-display UNCLAIMED       
           description: VGA compatible controller
           product: UHD Graphics
           vendor: Intel Corporation
           physical id: 2
           bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
           version: 02
           width: 64 bits
           clock: 33MHz
           capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
           configuration: latency=0
           resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:400-3ff memory:6024000000-6024ffffff memory:4000000000-400fffffff ioport:5000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

How can I fix this?

I already reinstalled the intel drivers

```
sudo apt-get purge xserver-xorg-video-intel && sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-intel
```

I believe the above message means the driver is not loaded?

How can I debug that further?

Comment: I have a similar issue after an update to 20.04, the HDMI port on my Dell Precision 5540 just stopped working.

I too see Intel VGA ( Intel UHD 630 ) using i915 as UNCLAIMED. When I boot with without `nomodeset` and `prime-select intel` I can't get past the login screen with failures at the GUI level.

Answer (score 1):

The driver for the intel card is i915. I saw that in `lspci -nnk`

```
Kernel modules: i915
```

so I tried `modprobe i915` which showed an error about the option `enable_dpcd_backlight`

After commenting out that

```
options i915 enable_dpcd_backlight
```

in `/etc/modprobe.d/tuxedo-i915.conf`

the driver seems to run.

But at least my main problem is solved for now.