# No HDMI audio device on intel_snd_hda (Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: sound, kernel, alsa, hdmi

I have a home server that I want to use as a media server.

But when I connect to a TV, there is no sound.

I've tried to update to latest available kernel, and also switch kernel module snd-hda-intel to generic. This fixes issues with no sound device, and now 3.5 jack works, but still no HDMI.

Some extra info:

`inxi`

```
System:    Kernel: 5.13.13-051313-generic x86_64 bits: 64 Console: tty 1 
           Distro: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS (Focal Fossa) 
Machine:   Type: Desktop Mobo: ASRock model: Z590M-ITX/ax serial: M80-E1004401592 UEFI: American Megatrends LLC. v: P1.00 
           date: 01/11/2021 
Audio:     Device-1: Intel driver: snd_hda_intel 
           Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.13.13-051313-generic
```

`aplay -l`

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: Generic Analog [Generic Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

videocard info (it is integrated GPU in i5-10400):

```
Intel Corporation Device 9bc8 (rev 03)

  *-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 03
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:a0000000-a0ffffff memory:90000000-9fffffff ioport:4000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

Comment: Sound via HDMI or DisplayPort depend on the graphics card, discrete or integrated. If Nvidia then typically proprietary drivers are needed. Please edit the question and post that hardware specification.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I've using integrated graphics card. Update the question.

Comment: So "display UNCLAIMED" is the problem. It isn't running any graphics drivers therefore HDMI audio can't possibly work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [unclaimed Intel video card after upgrade to 20.04 and reinstalling ubuntu-desktop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1254325/unclaimed-intel-video-card-after-upgrade-to-20-04-and-reinstalling-ubuntu-deskto)

Comment: @ChanganAuto unclaimed display because of ssh session, `modprode i915` does not show any errors.

Comment: Sorry if this is a distraction but it may be relevant. Do you have any screen sizing issues on that TV? Because when I travel I often HDMI into the TV to watch some movies. A lot of times the screen it cutting off say 2% of all 4 sides and it does not really stop youi dong what you want. HOWEVER if I resize, fit, or zoom to address that issue THE SOUND GOES AWAY. And when I reset it and the picture goes back to the crappy wierd sizing the sound comes back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update you BIOS - you are running version 1.0 and the current version is 1.4. You will have to do this manually since ASRock doesn't support the LVFS project.

If `lshw` lists a device as `UNCLAIMED`, then there is no driver loaded for this device. You can check this with `lspci -nk -s 00:02.0` - the output should include `Kernel driver in use:`. Also your `lshw` output would show `configuration: driver=<driver> latency=0`

Try `rmmod i915; modprobe -vvv i915` and check `dmesg` or `/var/log/syslog`. Since it appears you are running a mainline kernel, maybe try v5.14.